# "if" loop isn't matching a string length test

Tags: python, string, list, if-statement, enumerate

I have a list of strings that I am running a for loop on. The logic has been working without issue, but I had to add a new first `if` statement to check for indices where the string within is longer than a certain length. I don't seem to be able to get that statement to match even though some of my lengths show longer than 60. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the code:

```
for idx, x in enumerate(final_vlan_list_build2):
    length = len(final_vlan_list_build2[idx])
    print(length)
    print(type(length))
    if length >= 60:
        final_vlan_list_build2[idx] = final_vlan_list_build2[idx].replace(
            final_vlan_list_build2[idx], final_vlan_list_build2[idx] + "   default 1       none qtagged")
    elif 'qtagged' in x:
        final_vlan_list_build2[idx] = final_vlan_list_build2[idx]
    elif 'qtagged' and 'default' not in x:
        final_vlan_list_build2[idx] = final_vlan_list_build2[idx].replace(
            final_vlan_list_build2[idx], final_vlan_list_build2[idx] + "   default 1       none qtagged")
    else:
        final_vlan_list_build2[idx] = final_vlan_list_build2[idx].replace(
            final_vlan_list_build2[idx], (final_vlan_list_build2[idx] + '       none qtagged'))
print(final_vlan_list_build2)
```

FYI the lengths for each index definitely show some over 60:

```
10
<class 'int'>
10
<class 'int'>
32
<class 'int'>
32
<class 'int'>
50
<class 'int'>
30
<class 'int'>
32
<class 'int'>
76
<class 'int'>
54
<class 'int'>
33
<class 'int'>
55
<class 'int'>
77
<class 'int'>
31
<class 'int'>
33
<class 'int'>
33
<class 'int'>
31
<class 'int'>
71
<class 'int'>
31

Partial input list:
['int g1/0/1', 'int g1/0/2', 'int g1/0/3  3999    default     ', 'int g1/0/4  3999    default     ', 'int g1/0/5   261    qtagged
 368    default   ', 'int g1/0/6   368    default   ', 'int g1/0/7  3999    default     ', 'int g1/0/8   258    qtagged        261
qtagged       3999    default     ', 'int g1/0/9   261    qtagged       3999    default     ', 'int g1/0/10   368    default     ', 'int g1/0/11   261    qtagged       3999    default     ', 'int g1/0/12   258    qtagged        261    qtagged       3999    default
 ', 'int g1/0/13   367    default   ', 'int g1/0/14  3999    default     ', 'int g
...

The partial output list:
['int g1/0/1   default 1       none qtagged', 'int g1/0/2   default 1       none qtagged', 'int g1/0/3  3999    default            none qtagged', 'int g1/0/4  3999    default            none qtagged', 'int g1/0/5   261    qtagged      368    default   ', 'int g1/0/6
 368    default          none qtagged', 'int g1/0/7  3999    default            none qtagged', 'int g1/0/8   258    qtagged        261    qtagged       3999    default        default 1       none qtagged', 'int g1/0/9   261    qtagged       3999    default     ', 'int g1/0/10   368    default            none qtagged', 'int g1/0/11   261    qtagged       3999    default     ', 'int g1/0/12   258    qtagged        261    qtagged       3999    default        default 1       none qtagged',
.....
```

Comment: Why are you using `x.replace(x,x+y)` why you could just use `+=`?

Comment: `'qtagged' and 'default' not in x` evaluates as `'default' not in x` becasue any string with length > 0 evaluates to true so you are looking at `True and 'default' not in x`

Comment: Mostly me just being a newbie and not knowing all the shortcuts. I'll probably clean that up once I figure out why my first test isn't passing.

Comment: You're checking the length just fine. Perhaps you are getting confused because you have the modifications as a result for len>60 as you do for  'qtagged' and 'default' not in x...

Comment: Yeah...it's the same modification, but it's not actually making the modification. if you look at g1/0/8 in the input and output,, that's one that exceeds 60, but doesn't get changed in the output.

Comment: ah wait...I see the issue! I'm adding to the existing rather than replacing it completely.

Comment: Just changed that line to:        if length >= 60:
            final_vlan_list_build2[idx] = final_vlan_list_build2[idx].replace(
                final_vlan_list_build2[idx],"   default 1       none qtagged")

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem is not because you do the same action if lenght>60 and if 'qtagged' and 'default' not in x? 
So your result is not because of length but because of  if 'qtagged' and 'default' not in x...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if this is shitty but you're code is really hard to read. This is the same thing with 2 changes. First if the length is greater than 60 it replaces that element with "   default 1       none qtagged" and second I replaced the logic `'qtagged' and 'default' not in x` with `'qtagged' not in x and 'default' not in x` because that's what I assume you are trying todo.

```
for idx, x in enumerate(final_vlan_list_build2):
    if len(final_vlan_list_build2[idx]) >= 60:
        final_vlan_list_build2[idx] = "   default 1       none qtagged"
    elif 'qtagged' in x:
        pass
    elif 'qtagged' not in x and 'default' not in x:
        final_vlan_list_build2[idx] += "   default 1       none qtagged"
    else:
        final_vlan_list_build2[idx] += '       none qtagged'
print(final_vlan_list_build2)
```

Comment: no worries. I know it's a bit messy. But you helped me think through what I was doing wrong and I think i have it now. So thank you for that!